# kivy python passing parameters to fuction with button click

Tags: python, function, button, kivy

I am having trouble passing parameters to function when calling it with button press. One could do it like this in kivy language:

```
Button: 
   on_press: root.my_function('btn1')
```

but I would like to do it in python, as I would like to create a larger number of buttons with a loop. Currently I call my function in python like this:

```
Button(on_press=self.my_function)
```

but as I said, if I try to pass a parameter to the function like this, I get an 'AssertionError: None is not callable', like this:

```
Button(on_press=self.my_function('btn1'))
```

Answer (score 16):

```
Button(on_press=self.my_function)
```

This is *passing* the function as an argument.

```
Button(on_press=self.my_function('btn1'))
```

This is *calling* the function and passing the *returned value* as the argument to `on_press`. Since the returned value is None, you get your error.

You instead need to pass a new function that calls your normal function and automatically passes the argument. In general, it's convenient to use `functools.partial`:

```
from functools import partial
Button(on_press=partial(self.my_function, 'btn1'))
```

You can also use a lambda function:

```
Button(on_press=lambda *args: self.my_function('btn1', *args))
```