# Kivy error while trying to change the screen

Tags: python-3.x, kivy

I didn't want to use the `.kv` language. So my problem occurs when trying to run a function when I press a button.
I found these question which had the same problem so I adopted the code, for the on_press method, from them:
[kivy python passing parameters to fuction with button click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39809206/kivy-python-passing-parameters-to-fuction-with-button-click)
[Python, Kivy, “AssertionError: None is not callable” Error on function call by button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41817607/python-kivy-assertionerror-none-is-not-callable-error-on-function-call-by-b)

**The Error**

```
File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 703, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 1214, in kivy._event.EventObservers.dispatch
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 1138, in kivy._event.EventObservers._dispatch
   File "C:\Users\schup\PycharmProjects\Workspace\kivy_app_go\Surface.py", line 28, in <lambda>
     btnHvH = Button(text="Human vs Human", size_hint=(0.35, 0.15), on_release=lambda *args: self.HelperMethodsInst.switch_screen(goal_screen="go_screen", Screenmanager=WindowManager.get_ScreenManager, *args))
 TypeError: switch_screen() got multiple values for argument 'Screenmanager'
```

**Surface.py:**

```py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy_app_go.Control import HelperMethods
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.graphics import Rectangle, Color, Line
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import FadeTransition

from functools import partial


class MenuScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Screen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.ScreenSize = Window.size
        self.HelperMethodsInst = HelperMethods()

        lytmain = FloatLayout(size=self.ScreenSize)
        lytbutton = BoxLayout(pos_hint={"y": 0.1, "x": 0.15}, size_hint=(2, 0.6), orientation='vertical', size=self.ScreenSize)

        lblHeadline = Label(text="Choose your Go Mode", font_size=40, pos_hint={"y": 0.8, "x": 0.325},
                            size_hint=(0.35, 0.15))
        btnHvH = Button(text="Human vs Human", size_hint=(0.35, 0.15), on_release=lambda *args: self.HelperMethodsInst.switch_screen(goal_screen="go_screen", Screenmanager=WindowManager.get_ScreenManager, *args))
        btnHvB = Button(text="Human vs Bot", size_hint=(0.35, 0.15), on_release=lambda *args: self.HelperMethodsInst.switch_screen(goal_screen="go_screen", Screenmanager=WindowManager.get_ScreenManager, *args))
        btnBvB = Button(text="Bot vs Bot", size_hint=(0.35, 0.15), on_release=lambda *args: self.HelperMethodsInst.switch_screen(goal_screen="go_screen", Screenmanager=WindowManager.get_ScreenManager, *args))

        self.add_widget(lytmain)
        lytmain.add_widget(lblHeadline)
        lytmain.add_widget(lytbutton)
        lytbutton.add_widget(btnHvH)
        lytbutton.add_widget(btnHvB)
        lytbutton.add_widget(btnBvB)



class GoScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(GoScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.ScreenSize = Window.size

        lytmain = FloatLayout(size=self.ScreenSize)

        btnBack = Button(text="Back", size_hint=(0.25, 0.1))

        self.add_widget(lytmain)
        lytmain.add_widget(btnBack)


class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    def __init__(self):
        self.sm = ScreenManager(transition=FadeTransition(duration=0.15))
        self.sm.add_widget(MenuScreen(name="menu_screen"))
        self.sm.add_widget(GoScreen(name="go_screen"))

    @property
    def get_ScreenManager(self):
        return self.sm

class Surface(App):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.WindowManagerInst = WindowManager()

    def build(self):
        return self.WindowManagerInst.sm

    @staticmethod
    def create_Surface():
        return Surface().run()


def run():
    SurfaceInst = Surface()
    HelperMethodsInst = HelperMethods()
```

**Control.py:**

```py
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen


class HelperMethods:
    def switch_screen(self, Screenmanager, goal_screen):
        screenmanager = goal_screen
```

**main.py:**

```py
from kivy_app_go.Surface import Surface

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Surface.create_Surface()
```

I am new to kivy.
I hope someone can help ^^

Comment: Your `WindowManager` is a `ScreenManager`, but you are creating yet another `ScreenManager` with your line `self.sm = ScreenManager(transition=FadeTransition(duration=0.15))`. Try replacing `self.sm` with just `self` in that class. And in your `build` method just return `self.WindowManagerInst`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the

> multiple values for argument 'Screenmanager'

error because your `lambda` is constructing a function with keyword arguments followed by `*args`. Since positional arguments must come before keyword arguments, your `*args` is treated as part of the `Screenmanager=` keyword. So that keyword is passed to your `switch_screen` method as

```
Screenmanager = WindowManager.get_ScreenManager, *args
```

If you need the `Button` instance (which is what the `*args` is) passed to your `switch_screen` method, then you need to modify that method to accept it (and adjust the lambda).

You can avoid the error simply by removing the `*args` from the end of the `lambda`.

However, there is another problem in that same line of code. You are using `WindowManager.get_ScreenManager`, but `WindowManager` is a class, not an instance, and in the class file `get_ScreenManager` is a property. So you need the `WindowManager` instance, which you can get from the `WindowManagerInst` attribute of the `App`. So that line now become: (along with a call to get the running `App`):

```
app = App.get_running_app()
btnHvH = Button(text="Human vs Human", size_hint=(0.35, 0.15), on_release=lambda *args: self.HelperMethodsInst.switch_screen(goal_screen="go_screen", Screenmanager=app.WindowManagerInst.get_ScreenManager))
```