# After I start the program Kivy crashes without any error message

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

I am trying to program a GUI with kivy in python. I had before this question already a Problem with my code that got resolved:
[Kivy error while trying to change the screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59698450/kivy-error-while-trying-to-change-the-screen)
Now when I start the program the screen goes white and crashes without any error message.
I am trying to switch the Screen when I hit one of the button in the menu screen.

**Stacktrace:**

```
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.10.1
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.6.7 (default, Feb 28 2019, 07:28:18) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 194 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_pil, img_gif (img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Using the "OpenGL" graphics system
[INFO   ] [GL          ] GLEW initialization succeeded
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Backend used <glew>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <b'4.5.0 NVIDIA 385.54'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <b'NVIDIA Corporation'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <b'GeForce GTX 1050 Ti/PCIe/SSE2'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 4, 5
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Shading version <b'4.50 NVIDIA'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max size <32768>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max units <32>
[INFO   ] [Window      ] auto add sdl2 input provider
[INFO   ] [Window      ] virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked

Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)
```

**Surface.py:**

```py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy_app_go.Control import HelperMethods
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.graphics import Rectangle, Color, Line
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import FadeTransition

from functools import partial


class MenuScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Screen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.ScreenSize = Window.size
        self.HelperMethodsInst = HelperMethods()
        self.app = App.get_running_app()

        lytmain = FloatLayout(size=self.ScreenSize)
        lytbutton = BoxLayout(pos_hint={"y": 0.1, "x": 0.15}, size_hint=(2, 0.6), orientation='vertical', size=self.ScreenSize)

        lblHeadline = Label(text="Choose your Go Mode", font_size=40, pos_hint={"y": 0.8, "x": 0.325},
                            size_hint=(0.35, 0.15))
        btnHvH = Button(text="Human vs Human", size_hint=(0.35, 0.15),
                        on_release=lambda *args: self.HelperMethodsInst.switch_screen(goal_screen="go_screen", Screenmanager=self.app.WindowManagerInst.get_ScreenManager))
        btnHvB = Button(text="Human vs Bot", size_hint=(0.35, 0.15),
                        on_release=lambda *args: self.HelperMethodsInst.switch_screen(goal_screen="go_screen", Screenmanager=self.app.WindowManagerInst.get_ScreenManager))
        btnBvB = Button(text="Bot vs Bot", size_hint=(0.35, 0.15),
                        on_release=lambda *args: self.HelperMethodsInst.switch_screen(goal_screen="go_screen", Screenmanager=self.app.WindowManagerInst.get_ScreenManager))

        self.add_widget(lytmain)
        lytmain.add_widget(lblHeadline)
        lytmain.add_widget(lytbutton)
        lytbutton.add_widget(btnHvH)
        lytbutton.add_widget(btnHvB)
        lytbutton.add_widget(btnBvB)



class GoScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(GoScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.ScreenSize = Window.size

        lytmain = FloatLayout(size=self.ScreenSize)

        btnBack = Button(text="Back", size_hint=(0.25, 0.1))

        self.add_widget(lytmain)
        lytmain.add_widget(btnBack)


class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    def __init__(self):
        # self.sm = ScreenManager(transition=FadeTransition(duration=0.15))
        self.add_widget(MenuScreen(name="menu_screen"))
        self.add_widget(GoScreen(name="go_screen"))

    @property
    def get_ScreenManager(self):
        return self


class Surface(App):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.WindowManagerInst = WindowManager()

    def build(self):
        return self.WindowManagerInst

    @staticmethod
    def create_Surface():
        return Surface().run()


def run():
    SurfaceInst = Surface()
    HelperMethodsInst = HelperMethods()
```

**Control.py:**

```py
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen


class HelperMethods:
    def switch_screen(self, Screenmanager, goal_screen):
        print("pressed")
        print(screenmanager)
        print(screen)
        screenmanager = goal_screen
```

**main.py:**

```py
from kivy_app_go.Surface import Surface

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Surface.create_Surface()
```

Hope someone can help me ^^

Comment: I don't understand the description of the problem - what does "the screen goes white" mean? The whole screen? The Kivy window? And when does it "crash"? How long does the white screen last?

Comment: the whole window is white and then it crashed after a second let's say immediately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `WindowManager` class, you need to modify the `__init__` method to include a call to `super`:

```
class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    def __init__(self):
        super(WindowManager, self).__init__()
        # self.sm = ScreenManager(transition=FadeTransition(duration=0.15))
        self.add_widget(MenuScreen(name="menu_screen"))
        self.add_widget(GoScreen(name="go_screen"))
```

Comment: Thanks the program doesn't crash anymore but when I press the button I get the error message: `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'screenmanager' referenced before assignment`. Can you help me with that?

Comment: @Lupos The `HelperMethods.switch_screen()` method has a `Screenmanager` parameter, but uses `screenmanager` as variable inside. Notice the capital `S`. You should use a proper IDE/code editor/linter which will pick this up immediately.

Answer (score 1):

I had an issue with my Kivy app wasn't showing any info message or error. Was fixed after suggesting from @el3phanten to delete the log file at:

```
~/.kivy/config.ini
```

No I can see info and error messages:

```
$ python3 main.py 
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in /home/user/.kivy/logs/kivy_21-11-03_16.txt
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v2.0.0
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "/home/user/dev/kiwi/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kivy/__init__.py"
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.8.10 (default, Sep 28 2021, 16:10:42) 
[GCC 9.3.0]
[INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at "/home/user/dev/kiwi/venv/bin/python3"
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 186 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2 (img_pil, img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Using the "OpenGL" graphics system
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Backend used <sdl2>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <b'4.3 (Compatibility Profile) Mesa 21.0.3'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <b'nouveau'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <b'NVC1'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 4, 3
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Shading version <b'4.30'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max size <16384>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max units <16>
[INFO   ] [Window      ] auto add sdl2 input provider
[INFO   ] [Window      ] virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked
[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [title       ] This is a info message.
[INFO   ] [title       ] This is a info message.
[INFO   ] [Clipboard   ] Provider: xsel(['clipboard_xclip'] ignored)
[INFO   ] [CutBuffer   ] cut buffer support enabled
[INFO   ] [Base        ] Start application main loop
[INFO   ] [GL          ] NPOT texture support is available
[WARNING] <kivy.uix.gridlayout.GridLayout object at 0x7ff070d98740> have no cols or rows set, layout is not triggered.
[INFO   ] [Base        ] Leaving application in progress...
[INFO   ] [title       ] This is a info message.
```