# Kivy stopped without returning error message

Tags: python, error-handling, crash, kivy

Hi I have a pretty complex kivy application. I was doing some stuff, I started the app but when I was trying to save the data, my app suddenly stopped without any error message: `Process finished with exit code 1`

After reflexion, I found out that I deleted a key on the dict I was iterating on !

So I should have seen `RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration` but nothing appeared ! Why and how to prevent  this ?

(it can take al ong time to debug, I can't imagine without error message !).

Here is an example of a code that raise the needed error:

```
d = {"a":"e","b":"c"}
for k in d:
    del d[k]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you did not provide any code, I can't give you a specific answer, but:

This error occurs very often when using a method such as

> pop()

It happens, because you remove an item, while you are still iterating through your dictionary. If python now tries to access this very item, it can't and raises the error you mentioned.

This is easily solved by iterating over a copy of the dictionary and changing the values of the original while doing so.

This can be accomplished like this:

```
for i in original_dict.copy():
```

EDIT 1: To force python to show the error, you could do this:

```
try:

    # your code

except Exception as e:

    raise e
```

Comment: @NoameKhan72, ```If python now tries to access this very item, it can't and raises the error you mentioned.```, hum actually I was able to raise this error on another little program, I added an example above, this is why I'm worried when I can't raise it on my kivy programm.

Comment: I'm not sure, whether I fully understand your problem now. I was able to reproduce the error using your example. 
I was also able to fix it using the suggested copy method.
Was this not what you wanted? Please clarify.

Comment: I'm not worried about the error, I'm worried that it wasn't raised on my complex kivy app but it was raised on the simple example.

Comment: Does the Edit solve your problem? I have never heard of Kivy not raising the error, maybe something went wrong with your installation? Do you have all the necessary files?

Comment: Nope, it's on my PyCharm IDE, I didn't even deploy ! I think I have everything.

Comment: Can you create a Minimal working example for me to reproduce the error on my machine? Otherwise I can only guess what would solve the issue. Have you tried the try-except method?

Answer (score 0):

Check this answer [After I start the program Kivy crashes without any error message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59702748/after-i-start-the-program-kivy-crashes-without-any-error-message/69827953#69827953)

basically if your kivy app no longer show info or error messages, just try to delete your config file at:

```
~/.kivy/config.ini
```