# Not Sure why this is not Callable when Its a method

Tags: python, kivy

So I am not sure why my one method doesn't override the current on_press bind. I tried to used the .unbind method and that also didn't work. I tried to use the lambda and that really only worked if I was changing only one of the buttons. I want to create a chart that upon clicking a tuple, I can change the number using a "+" button. When I click another tuple, I can change that one using the same "+" button. Using lambda changed both of them simultaneously

```
def PlusOne(buttonValue):
    Result = float(buttonValue.text) + 1
    buttonValue.text = str(Result)
    print(str(buttonValue.text))

def ButtonPlusOne(button):
    global x

    if x == 1:
       self.plusButton.unbind(on_press=PlusOne(button))
       self.plusButton.bind(on_press=PlusOne(button))
       print(str(button.text))
    else:
       self.plusButton.bind(on_press=PlusOne(button))
       print(str("ElsePrint " + button.text))
       x = 1

self.Button1.bind(on_press=ButtonPlusOne(self.Button1))
self.Button2.bind(on_press=ButtonPlusOne(self, self.Button2))
```

This would return    AssertionError: None is not callable

Comment: Try debugging it and see the state of 'plusButton' at that point in time.  is it the object you expect it to be? self.plusButton is never assigned in this code.

Comment: `on_press` is meant to be assigned to a function, not the result of calling one.

Answer (score 0):

The `on_press` argument would look like so,

`self.Button1.bind(on_press=ButtonPlusOne)`

which would call `ButtonPlusOne()` passing in the instance of `self.Button1` already.

The error is because Kivy is trying to run `ButtonPlusOne(self.Button1)(self.Button1)` or `None(self.Button1)`, which is the error you get.

---

Your `PlusOne` function seems fine (however, seems you might be doing `float('+') + 1`, which is a separate issue), but again, the binding would need to be `on_press=PlusOne`

I dont think rebinding the same function to plusButton will change any behavior

If you want to pass references to the other button labels from the "plus button", you might want to look into [partial functions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39809268/2308683)

Comment: This worked! As a new python/kivy programmer this explained so much for me. Thanks so much.